# How to ping a set of IPs stored in a text file and validate where the IP is reachable or not in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ping

I am very new to Ruby so any help will be very useful. :)

What I aim to do with my program is:

1. Open a txt file with a list of IPs stored in it
2. Fetch each IP one by one and ping it
3. If the IP is reachable, return a TRUE value
4. If IP is unreachable, return a FALSE value
5. All non-reachable IPs to be written into another txt file

Below is the program I pieced together from different online help sources:

```
require 'timeout'
require 'socket'

#PING LOGIC
class Ping 
  def self.pingecho(host, timeout=5, service="echo")
    puts host
    begin
      while(timeout) do
        s = TCPSocket.new(host, service)     
        s.close
      end
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
      return true
    rescue   Timeout::Error, StandardError 
      return false 
    end
    return true
  end
end

#opening the file with list of IPs
File.open('Ips.xml', 'r'). each do |line|    
 hostip = line
 #passing each line to the class for the ping test
  if (p Ping.pingecho(hostip) == 'true')
    return
  else
    #writing all non-reachable IPs to another file
    File.open('Not reachable.txt','a') do |linea|
    linea.puts hostip + "\n"
  end   
end
end
```

This does not give me any error when I execute it, but provides a FALSE result for all IPs in the txt file which I know are reachable.

I know that separately all the components of this program work fine: The ping logic works fine if I just pass an IP directly to it (For example: p Ping.pingecho("10.40.220.34")).

The file opening; reading; and writing into other file also work fine as I tested them separately.

The issue seems to be with the manner in which the IP is passed to the class from the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (p Ping.pingecho(hostip) == 'true')
> ```

`Ping::pingecho` returns either `true` or `false`, but it never returns `'true'`, therefore this condition will always be false, and the conditional expression will always evaluate the `else` branch.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried replacing if (p Ping.pingecho(hostip) == 'true') with if (p Ping.pingecho(hostip) == true) but the result is still wrong :(

Comment: `p "foo"` returns "foo", not true. If you want to `p` there, use `if Ping.pingecho(hostip).tap { |res| p res }`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

The issue is resolved now. It appears that the way the data was stored in my input file was the problem. I have fixed that and the code works fine now. :)